# Forcing evaluation of prefetched results in django queries

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to use `select_related/prefetch_related` to optimize some queries. However I have issues in "forcing" the queries to be evaluated all at once.

Say I'm doing the following:

```
fp_query = Fourprod.objects.filter(choisi=True).select_related("fk_fournis")    
pf = Prefetch("fourprod", queryset=fp_query)                # 
products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=fp_query).prefetch_related(pf)
```

With models:

```
class Fourprod(models.Model):
    fk_produit = models.ForeignKey(to=Produit, related_name="fourprod")
    fk_fournis = models.ForeignKey(to=Fournis,related_name="fourprod")
    choisi = models.BooleanField(...)


class Produit(models.Model):
    ... ordinary fields... 

class Fournis(models.Model):
    ... ordinary fields...
```

So essentially, `Fourprod` has a fk to `Fournis`, `Produit`, and I want to prefetch those when I build the `Produits` queryset. I've checked in debug that the prefetch actually occurs and it does.

I have a bunch of fields from different models I need to use to compute results. I don't really control the table structure, so I have to work with this. I can't come up with a reasonable query to do it all with the queries (or using raw), so I want to compute stuff python-side. It's a few 1000 objects, so reasonable to do in-memory. So I cast to a list to force the query evaluation:

```
products = list(products)
```

At this point, I would think that the `Products` *and* the related objects that I have pre-fetched should have been fetched from the DB. In the logs, just after the list() call, I get this:

```
02/08/22 15:21:08 DEBUG DEFAULT: (0.019) SELECT "products_fourprod"."id", "products_fourprod"."fk_produit_id", "products_fourprod"."fk_fournis_id", "products_fourprod"."choisi", "products_fourprod"."code_four", "products_fourprod"."prix", "products_fourprod"."comment", "products_fournis"."id", "products_fournis"."fk_user_create_id", "products_fournis"."nom", "products_fournis"."adresse", "products_fournis"."ville", "products_fournis"."tel", "products_fournis"."fax", "products_fournis"."contact", "products_fournis"."note", "products_fournis"."pays", "products_fournis"."province", "products_fournis"."postal", "products_fournis"."monnaie", "products_fournis"."tel_long", "products_fournis"."inactif", "products_fournis"."inuse", "products_fournis"."par", "products_fournis"."fk_langue", "products_fournis"."NOTE2" FROM "products_fourprod" LEFT OUTER JOIN "products_fournis" ON ("products_fourprod"."fk_fournis_id" = "products_fournis"."id") WHERE ("products_fourprod"."choisi" AND "products_fourprod"."fk_produit_id" IN (... all Product.id meeting the conditions...)
```

But then, the list comprehension using the products takes forever to complete:

```
rows = [[p.id, p.fourprod.first().id, p.desuet, p.no_prod, ... ] for p in products]
```

With apparently each single call to p.fourprod resulting in a DB hit:

```
02/08/22 15:26:19 DEBUG DEFAULT: (0.000) SELECT "products_fourprod"."id", "products_fourprod"."fk_produit_id", "products_fourprod"."fk_fournis_id", "products_fourprod"."choisi", "products_fourprod"."code_four", "products_fourprod"."prix", "products_fourprod"."comment", "products_fournis"."id", "products_fournis"."fk_user_create_id", "products_fournis"."nom", "products_fournis"."adresse", "products_fournis"."ville", "products_fournis"."tel", "products_fournis"."fax", "products_fournis"."contact", "products_fournis"."note", "products_fournis"."pays", "products_fournis"."province", "products_fournis"."postal", "products_fournis"."monnaie", "products_fournis"."tel_long", "products_fournis"."inactif", "products_fournis"."inuse", "products_fournis"."par", "products_fournis"."fk_langue", "products_fournis"."NOTE2" FROM "products_fourprod" LEFT OUTER JOIN "products_fournis" ON ("products_fourprod"."fk_fournis_id" = "products_fournis"."id") WHERE ("products_fourprod"."choisi" AND "products_fourprod"."fk_produit_id" = 1185) ORDER BY "products_fourprod"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; args=(1185,)
02/08/22 15:26:19 DEBUG DEFAULT: (0.000) SELECT "products_fourprod"."id", (.... more similar db hits... )
```

If I remove all the uses of related objects, then the list() call has actually forced the db hit already and the query executes quickly.

So.... if simply calling     `products = list(products)` *does not* force the db to be queried for the prefetched objects as well, is there any ways I can make django's orm do so?

Comment: If prefetch doesn't work then it means that your query is trying to access instances that are not in cached results and prefetch is ignored. I'm pretty sure that `Products.objects.filter(id__in=fp_query)` is a culprit. I don't understand why you are filtering `Products` by `Fourprod` ids. It's totally different model.

Comment: No there are instance in ._state.field_items and in ._prefetch_instances_objects. You're right that the filtering is wrong, it should actually be id__in=fp_query.values_list(fk_produit__id, flat=True). But that's not the issue. As mentionned that the models I have to work with.

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that `Products.objects.filter(id__in=fp_query)` is an issue here. Try something like: `Products.objects.all().prefetch_related(pf)`.

Comment: `first()` implies a database query, so that will cause your query to not use the prefetched values. Try to use `p.fourprod.all()[0]` instead. Can you also share how you print the sql executed by django? The prefetch should have been on the same call for `list(products)`

Comment: @BrianDestura .first() forcing the DB query for the win. That was the source of the issue. If you want to write an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll do it & accept it, referencing this comment. For the SQL print, I just used django's debugger/logging configured in settings.py

Comment: Ok I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

> Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.

`first()` implies a database query, so that will cause your query to not use the prefetched values.

Try to use `p.fourprod.all()[0]` instead to access the first related `fourprod` instead.